# How to view Dynamic Images in Crystal Report 9 during runtime without using Database?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I encounter this problem because im using crystal report 9 and I can't view Dynamic images in my Reports.

The scenario is like this.

The user will just browse the image and be the picture to my report. The reason i will not save it to database because it will only used once and if i will save it, it is a burden to my database.

I search a lot and the solution is the `Graphic Location` in Crystal Report but it is only supported in Crystal Report XI i think..

Can anyone have an idea regarding this problem....

Im using C#..

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a dataset as the report data source:

1) Put the image data in a byte[] buffer

2) Put it into a column of type byte[] in your dataset: row[column] = buffer;

3) In Crystal, if your datasource is not the dataset, use a XSD file with a column of type base64Binary.

4) In Crystal, drag the field from the data source to the report.

Comment: Im not using dataset..the crystal report connect to the database..is there anyway that i can put the image in the crystal report?

Comment: Try using an OLE object (in context menu, insert, ole object). There must be a way to work with it dynamically, but i dont know how to do it, sorry. But you may try to vinculate it to a file dedicated to this report and save the select image by the user overwriting this file. But concurrency would be an issue.